# @PathParam value is always empty

Tags: web-services, jersey

I am trying to get the id from the url, but it always empty.

```
  @Path("/{id}")
  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Client returnXmlClient(@PathParam("id") String id) 
  {
     logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "value of id is={0} ", id);
     // ... other code
```

I am just starting to learn webServices,So please bare if it is something silly that i have Overlooked.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had imported the `Pathparam` from wrong package

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
```

it should have been

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
```

Comment: I was just bitten as well. And the worst part is that I already heard about it, and didn't think to check it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this annotation at method level
 @Consumes(MediaType.XXXXX)

Try to access your resource with correct uri

Comment: i added the annotation `@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})`  but it is still empty.

Comment: when i have the MediaType as `TEXT_PLAIN` only then id's value is null